# Imap Connection error

Tags: c#, email, imap

The exception in our `C#` program  is instantiating `ImapConnection()` and then fetching attachment, returning is the following:

```
Imap.ImapException: Failure fetching message from IMAP folder/mailbox.
```

So I took a look at a traffic dump and found the following:

```
REQUEST: IMAP FETCH BODY[1]
```

and the server is only responding:

```
IMAP OK Completed (0.000 sec)
```

But no message.

Any ideas on what might be going on here? Thanks for your help.

Ps. `Imap` server works fine

Comment: Are you sure the message does not have an empty body?

Comment: it is empty,am not sure, I am interested in attachment